# print a value with label.new using pine script

Tags: pine-script

I am doing a simple calculation and trying to print the value on screen in trading view using pine script.

When I do the printed value is wrong explained the issue below with example

H3 is 11540.49
L3 is 11491.71
diff = (11540.49 - 11491.71) = 48.78
where as i get 115.362

Let me know where I am doing the mistake, below is the code

```
study(title="printlabel",overlay=true)
yhigh=security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", high[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
ylow=security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", low[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
yclose = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
yopen = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

H3 = yclose + (yhigh-ylow) * 1.1/4
L3 = yclose - (yhigh-ylow) * 1.1/4

diff = H3-L3

var label1 = label.new(bar_index,high, text=tostring(diff), style=label.style_circle)
//label.set_x(label1, bar_index[10])
label.set_xloc(label1, time, xloc.bar_time)

 plot(H3,color = color.red)
 plot(L3,color = color.green)
```

[image: Screen shot of the indicator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your label is created on the first bar only and then updated on each bar, which is more efficient than continuously creating and deleting the label. So that's ideal, but musn't forget to update the label's text though. Here we also update the label's y position using the highest high in the last 10 bars, plus the true range. We use those values as evaluated on the previous bar so that our label doesn't move up and down during the realtime bar:

```
var label1 = label.new(bar_index, high, "", style=label.style_circle)
label.set_xloc(label1, time, xloc.bar_time)
label.set_text(label1, text=tostring(diff))
label.set_y(label1, highest(10)[1] + tr[1])
```